# Safe dynamic sql-query in java to change out .createNativeQuery

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have an application that uses EntityManager.createNativeQuery. Our quality gate(Sonar) is not so happy about it and shows me a critical error due to the risk of SQL-injection. Is there a "safe" way to create a dynamic sql-query in java?

My current code below:

```
return entityManager.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString(), MyClass.class).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection you could use parameter binding.

Example:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT title, author FROM books WHERE genre = ?1");
query.setParameter(1, "mystery");
```

You can find more examples [here](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa).

Comment: What if table name variable as well?

Answer (score 1):

First, Sonar will complain even if you cleanse the input to your query string. You may have to // NOSONAR that line.

Sonar can't tell if you've scanned all the externally provided inputs to your query string. For example, a name input of "Joe ' Bloggs" will break your query string. I can't see how your are building your query; it's up to you to make it safe by validating any externally provided values.